# How to resolve HTTP 403(requested via method [POST] has been blocked) error of R&R index documents API

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson, retrieve-and-rank

I tried to index 2 million documents in R&R, but got a HTTP403 error after about 830 thousands documents. I sent 'update API' request with 10 thousands document at once and repeat the operation by my customized tool. I succeeded until about 830 thousands, so I don't think that I mistook the basic authentication credentials.

```
> 2017-01-05T22:51:23.289Z - error: addDocs error: SolrError:
> {"solrErrorMessage":{"message":"WRRCSH001: The resource with path
> [jawiki_collection/update/json], parameters [{DD=[1],
> search_in_description=[1], sourceNode=[231772, 244365], hl=[ja],
> contentPK=[18393008, 17796905],  .... SESSIONKEY=[1410347259768]}],
> requested via method [POST] has been blocked."}}
> 
> Request URL:
> http://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/xxx/solr/jawiki_collection/update/json?&wt=json
> Request method: POST    Status code: 403 - Forbidden
```

My cluster resource doesn't seem to have a resource problem. There is free space in disk and memory.

```
curl -u "xxx:xxx" "https:
//gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/sc902e45b6_e043_4354_9922_30efd714bd80/stats"
{"disk_usage":{"used_bytes":4687192808,"total_bytes":240518168576,"used":"4.3653 GB","total":"224 GB","percent_used":1.9487894971721937},"memory_usage
":{"used_bytes":10471399424,"total_bytes":29360128000,"used":"9.7523 GB","total":"27.344 GB","percent_used":35.66537388392857}}
```

Could you teach me what is the cause of this HTTP403 error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

A 403 Forbidden error means that you do not have permission to view the requested file or resource. While sometimes this is intentional, other times it is due to misconfigured permissions.

The top reasons for this error are permissions or .htaccess error.

You can try fixing it anyway from this [link](https://www.lifewire.com/403-forbidden-error-explained-2617989)